# PHP: How to split varying length data into

Tags: php, arrays, split, field, explode

I'm reading data from an object (OLE binary file) and need to find a way to split the data into an array or other format so I can obtain the few pieces of information I need. I'm not sure how this can be achieved.

The data comes in like this:

> |some_other_delimited_data|RECORD=1|FIELD_1=A|FIELD_2=B|FIELD_3=C|RECORD=21|FIELD_1=C|FIELD_4=D|FIELD_5=E|RECORD=47|FIELD_6=F||RECORD=1|FIELD_1=G|FIELD_2=H|RECORD=37|FIELD_8=J|FIELD_9=K|FIELD_10=L|RECORD=40|FIELD_11=M|RECORD=47|FIELD_6=N|some_more_delimited_data|

Each data set starts with "RECORD=1" which contains a number of fields, followed by additional records. Each of these records (numbered 2-46) can occur multiple times and with a varying number of fields (ie RECORD=17 could occur five times and have a different number of fields for each one). The data set ends with RECORD=47 and its fields. A full set of data is contained between and including RECORD=1 and RECORD=47.

Multiple data sets exists so there are numerous "RECORD=1" to "RECORD=47" blocks that I need to get data from.

Each RECORD can have a varying number of fields.

Everything is separated by a "|" delimiter and there doesn't seem to be any other delimiters in the stream.

For each data set, I need to get:

- From RECORD=24, the data from FIELD_1 where FIELD_2="FOO"
- From RECORD=31, the data from FIELD_1 where FIELD_2="BAR"

How can this be done? I have multiple files that data needs to be pulled from each containing multiple data sets so it needs to be fairly efficient.

Comment: If its an OLE file can you use the `OLE` package to parse it? https://github.com/pear/OLE

Comment: This is not a complicated task.  Just try and keep trying.  To tokenize your data in PHP,  try creating functions,  try and error,  but do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to split the string:

```
$stream = "|some_other_delimited_data|RECORD=1|FIELD_1=A|FIELD_2=B|FIELD_3=C|RECORD=21|FIELD_1=C|FIELD_4=D|FIELD_5=E|RECORD=47|FIELD_6=F||RECORD=1|FIELD_1=G|FIELD_2=H|RECORD=37|FIELD_8=J|FIELD_9=K|FIELD_10=L|RECORD=40|FIELD_11=M|RECORD=47|FIELD_6=N|some_more_delimited_data|";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all ("/RECORD=([0-9]+)((\|FIELD_[0-9]+=[A-Z]+)+)/", $stream, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$array = array();
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $submatches = array();
    preg_match_all ("/\|FIELD_([0-9]+)=([A-Z]+)/", $match[2], $submatches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $fields = array();
    foreach($submatches as $submatch) {
        $fields[$submatch[1]] = $submatch[2];
    }
    $array[] = array('record' => $match[1], 'fields' => $fields);
}

print_r($array);
```

Extracting the desired values from the array should be easy now, use array_keys(), array_search() and array_column().